# how to restructure data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, newline

I'm new to Python. I need to restructure the inputed string data into entered/separated by carriage return characters like this one:

```
Input: D A P U R
       N U W A Y

Output: D   N
        A   U
        P   W
        U   A
        R   Y
```

I tried to use the `replace()` method but nothing solved. Below is my current code:

```
txt = input("Enter text: ")

def textSeparation(txt):
    t = txt.replace(" ", "\r\n")
    return t

res = textSeparation(txt)
print(res)
```

The inputed string is basicly separated by space characters. Is there any built-in function in Python to do this?

I have tried using built-in `replace()` to replace the space char with \r\n but nothing solved.

Comment: `input` can only return one line at a time.  Do you have two input statements?  The function you are looking for is `zip`, but we'd need to see the whole code.

Comment: No, there;s only one input statement

Comment: Then you can't possibly have two lines in there.

Comment: Will you always have two lines of input or there may be more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure there is a better way out there. But here is something that can do the job.

Note: Only works for this particular structure and equal number of characters.

First, I will assume that your input looks something like this:

```
input_string = "D A P U R\nN U W A Y"
```

Output:

```
D A P U R
N U W A Y
```

What you can do is
1- split the string on the line separator (\n)
2- convert each line to its list of characters
3- convert the result to a numpy array
4- transpose the array
5- join each row to form a string
6- join all rows to form a full string
This is done in this function:

```
def transpose_input(input_string):
    return '\n'.join([' '.join(l) for l in np.array([list(line.replace(' ', '')) for line in input_string.split('\n')]).T.tolist()])
```

Test:

```
input_string = "D A P U R\nN U W A Y"
new_string = transpose_input(input_string)

print(new_string)
```

Output:

```
D N
A U
P W
U A
R Y
```

Edit: without using numpy

```
def transpose_input(input_string):
    return '\n'.join([' '.join(l) for l in list(zip(*input.replace(' ', '').split('\n')))])
```

Test:

```
input_string = "D A P U R\nN U W A Y"
new_string = transpose_input(input_string)

print(new_string)
```

Output:

```
D N
A U
P W
U A
R Y
```

Edit 2: only if space separated

```
def transpose_input(input_string):
    return '\n'.join([' '.join(l) for l in list(zip(*[r.split(' ') for r in input_string.split('\n')]))])
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use any libraries

Comment: I've tried the edited one and it works but actually it transpose all character instead of the spaced character only. Note that I just want to separate the char between the space. So if there's no space, it shouldn't be transposed...

Comment: Check edit number 2.